# Moment.js DST conversion

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I'm receiving this string from database about a plant in Sao Paulo(Brazil):

"2018-10-30T14:10:40.423-03:00".

I'm trying to create a moment object using the commands

```
var dateFromDB = "2018-10-30T14:10:40.423-03:00";
var momentObj = moment.tz(dateFromDB, "America/Sao_Paulo")
```

but the format is incorrect

```
console.log(momentObj.format('L HH:mm:ss')) // I expect "10/30/2018 14:10:40"
```

But the result is "10/30/2018 15:10:40".

What is it wrong?

Comment: After running your code in my browser, i get the expected value.

Comment: Which browser? Chrome?

Comment: @Leo, format is right but time is work is it?

Comment: What is wrong is the hour: 15 instead of 14

Comment: DTS should be DST (Daylight Savings Time)?

Comment: there seems to be issue with timezone , check this link - https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/399

Comment: @Barmar exactly. The format seems to work correctly before the 21th of October and after the 3rd of November (but to test some dates after the 3rd of November is necessary to change the offset from -03:00 into -02:00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to Brazil's 2018 changes in DST dates, reflected in tzdb 2018c.

For Moment-Timezone, this is in version 0.5.15 or newer.  Upgrade to the latest version, and you should have the correct results.

Always remember - Time zones are decided by the various governments of the world.  They can, and do change.  Technology can reflect these decisions, but only if you stay on top of updates.